# Google Bigquery error 404 Not Found for dataset which exists

Tags: google-bigquery

I have dataset having name "data". I am getting an error 404 Not Found when trying to delete this dataset using Java API. 
I am able to create and delete table under this dataset. I wanted to delete this dataset but it returning an error. 
I tried this on Google Bigquery web console there I am getting an error "Unable to find dataset:data"

Comment: Try reloading the web UI. It might have already been deleted. Also, run `bq ls -d <project-id>`. Do you see the dataset listed there?

Comment: It will not work. I'm facing this from last week. Initially I thought that it will be deleted after some time but it is still there.

Comment: please share your code then

Comment: Having the same problem. @vvp did you figure out anything ?

Comment: Nope. I have reported this to Google but, No reply from Google.